# spark rdd filter after groupbykey

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

```
//create RDD
val rdd = sc.makeRDD(List(("a", (1, "m")), ("b", (1, "m")),
             ("a", (1, "n")), ("b", (2, "n")), ("c", (1, "m")), 
             ("c", (5, "m")), ("d", (1, "m")), ("d", (1, "n"))))
val groupRDD = rdd.groupByKey()
```

after `groupByKey` I want to filter the second element is not equal 1 and get

```
("b", (1, "m")),("b", (2, "n")), ("c", (1, "m")), ("c", (5, "m"))`
```

`groupByKey()` is must necessary, could help me, thanks a lot.

EDIT:

but if the second element type is string, filter the second element All of them equal `x` ,like

```
("a",("x","m")), ("a",("x","n")), ("b",("x","m")), ("b",("y","n")), ("c",("x","m")), ("c",("z","m")), ("d",("x","m")), ("d",("x","n"))
```

and also get the same result

```
("b",("x","m")), ("b",("y","n")), ("c",("x","m")), ("c",("z","m"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
val groupRDD = rdd
  .groupByKey()
  .filter(value => value._2.map(tuple => tuple._1).sum != value._2.size)
  .flatMapValues(list => list) // to get the result as you like, because right now, they are, e.g. (b, Seq((1, m), (1, n)))
```

What this does, is that we are first grouping keys through `groupByKey`, then we are filtering through `filter` by summing the keys from your grouped entries, and checking whether the `sum` is as much as the grouped entries size. For example:

```
(a, Seq((1, m), (1, n))   -> grouped by key
(a, Seq((1, m), (1, n), 2 (the sum of 1 + 1), 2 (size of sequence))
2 = 2, filter this row out
```

The final result:

```
(c,(1,m))
(b,(1,m))
(c,(5,m))
(b,(2,n))
```

Good luck!

**EDIT**

Under the assumption that `key` from tuple can be any string; assuming `rdd` is your data that contains:

```
(a,(x,m))
(c,(x,m))
(c,(z,m))
(d,(x,m))
(b,(x,m))
(a,(x,n))
(d,(x,n))
(b,(y,n))
```

Then we can construct `uniqueCount` as:

```
val uniqueCount = rdd
  // we swap places, we want to check for combination of (a, 1), (b, a), (b, b), (c, a), etc.
  .map(entry => ((entry._1, entry._2._1), entry._2._2))
  // we count keys, meaning that (a, 1) gives us 2, (b, a) gives us 1, (b, b) gives us 1, etc.
  .countByKey()
  // we filter out > 2, because they are duplicates
  .filter(a => a._2 == 1)
  // we get the very keys, so we can filter below
  .map(a => a._1._1)
  .toList
```

Then this:

```
val filteredRDD = rdd.filter(a => uniqueCount.contains(a._1))
```

Gives this output:

```
(b,(y,n))
(c,(x,m))
(c,(z,m))
(b,(x,m))
```

Comment: but if the second element type is string,filter the second element All of them equal `x` ,like ```("a",("x","m")), ("a",("x","n")), ("b",("x","m")), ("b",("y","n")), ("c",("x","m")), ("c",("z","m")), ("d",("x","m")), ("d",("x","n"))```

and also get the same result ```("b",("x","m")), ("b",("y","n")), ("c",("x","m")), ("c",("z","m"))```

Comment: updated the post, hope it's gonna work for you